# Keep monitoring user's location whenever it changes its position

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocation

I am new in location services. I have used `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and `(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` method but it is not getting called as I change location value. I want to fetch location value whenever user change its location.How should i achieve this? Please help me to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you assigned the CLLocationManagerDelegate?

Comment: @DheerajSingh Yes i have used myLocationManager.delegate = self; and assigned delegate to it.

Comment: are u using ios8? and could u show ur code

Comment: @DheerajSingh No ios 7 and i know for ios 8 we need to use "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" and i have done that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement "didUpdateLocations" delegate method . Here is sample

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"locations : %@",locations.description);

   CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"current location : %f %f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);



}
```

Comment: Please find my updated question and yes i have tried this method as well but it is not working.

Comment: didUpdateToLocation method is deprecated. If locationManager:didUpdateLocations: is
 implemented, this method will not be called.  Once check it

Comment: I am using your updateLocation method then it is not getting called . Why it is happening so?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 you need to do two extra things to get location working: 
1. add one or both of the following keys to your Info.plist file:

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

2. Next you need to request authorization for the corresponding location method, WhenInUse or Background. Use one of these calls:

   [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

   [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

For details refer following link. http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/